# How to compile Intel VNNI instructions with GCC or llvm?

Tags: gcc, llvm, intel

Intel has announced its new AVX512 extension instructions. I am working on the simulation of its VNNI instructions. I am referring to this manual https://software.intel.com/en-us/isa-extensions. I searched on google whether gcc or llvm has supported the VNNI instructions. I only found news that they are working on it. If anyone knows how to compile VNNI instructions(like instructions VPDPBUSD and VPDPWSSD) please share with me. Thanks alot!

Comment: [According to Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ice-Lake-VNNI-VBMI2-GCC), Intel sent patches for AVX512-VNNI [to the gcc mailing list in Oct 2017](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-10/msg01673.html), adding builtins for them.  (That link added `VPDPBUSD`, other messages in the patch-set do other things).  IDK if those were accepted into mainline or not, but if not then try building a gcc with them.

Comment: Are you hoping the compiler will auto-vectorize with them?  Or do you want to use them via Intel `__m512i` intrinsics, or GCC `__builtin_ia32_vpdpbusd_v8si`?  Or with inline asm, so you only need assembler support (binutils) if you're using gcc, or support from LLVM's built-in assembler.

Comment: Thanks for your information @PeterCordes, I have just found out gcc 7.3 version support VNNI instructions already. I can compile VNNI instructions with -mavx5124vnniw option(but -mavx512vnni option does not work).

Comment: AVX512-VNNI (Ice Lake) is a different extension from AVX-512 4VNNIW (Knight's Mill, next gen Xeon Phi, similar to AVX512-4FMAPS).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512 says there are no current plans to build any CPUs with both.  See also the "Instruction set" section of that page for a breakdown by which CPU introduces which extensions.

Comment: [Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer site](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) has nightly builds of gcc, and it's easy to try different command line options.

Comment: Related: current NASM source doesn't include `VPDPBUSD`. 
 https://github.com/cyrillos/nasm/blob/master/x86/insns.dat.

Answer (score 3):

The following flags allow the generation of AVX512-VNNI instructions

#### >= gcc 8.1, >= clang 7.0.0

- `-march=icelake-client`
- `-march=icelake-server`

#### >= gcc 9.1, >= clang 8.0.0

- `-march=cascadelake`

Tested with the Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/Pkci0J

Code sample downloaded from the following link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-vector-extensions-512-intel-avx-512-new-vector-neural-network-instruction